# Fancybox not showing media but IS loading lightbox

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, spring-webflow-2

On http://herfilms.tv/ I have fancybox running on the central image (the sofa), and when clicked I want it to load a specific vimeo video in an I frame.

As you can see, the I frame appears but the content is nowhere to be found.

What am I missing?

Regards,
Sam

Comment: `What am I missing?` : to post your code here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the embed content of the vimeo video not the link to the page.

ie:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/82215016" width="500" height="213" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/82215016">Rella - Unleash The Tiger</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/watchher">her</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

use the src from the embed tag as your anchor's href attribute:

like this:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="//player.vimeo.com/video/82215016">
          <img class="img" src="images/video1.jpg" id="video-1" alt="52e9005308c9b5800e000210_video1.jpg">
        </a>
```